# In Flexbox layout, how does browser handle width of flex items?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am studying CSS3 layout based on Flexboxes.

I usually use the portion of the power of flexboxes just to layout some navigation.

My quiestion is when property `flex` is being applied to child elements, how the browser handle the width of elements.

Here's some note:

[image]

Now it's confusing part...

[image]

When I use `flex-basis:300px` for `#child2` instead of using `width:300px`, same thing happens...

[image]

So is this the way it is?

Answer (score 3):

### The `flex-wrap` property

> **[5.2 Flex Line Wrapping: the flex-wrap property](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#propdef-flex-wrap)**
>
> The `flex-wrap` property controls whether the flex container is
>   [single-line](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#single-line) or [multi-line](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#multi-line), and the direction of the [cross-axis](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#cross-axis), which
>   determines the direction new lines are stacked in.

```
Value:      nowrap | wrap | wrap-reverse
Initial:    nowrap
```

As can be seen, the initial value of `flex-wrap` property is `nowrap` which [means](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#propdef-flex-wrap):

> **nowrap**
>
> The flex container **is** [single-line](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#single-line). The cross-start direction is
>   equivalent to either the inline-start or block-start direction of the
>   current writing mode, whichever is in the cross axis, and the
>   cross-end direction is the opposite direction of cross-start.

That being said, [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-item) would be placed in a single line *by default*, no matter how much their `width` is; *"even if that would cause contents to overflow."*

Therefore the used value should be `wrap` to create a [multi-line](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#multi-line) flex container which *"breaks its flex items across multiple lines"*

---

### How the browser handle the width of flex items

Flex items have the following by default:

- [`flex-grow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#propdef-flex-grow) of `0`
- [`flex-shrink`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#propdef-flex-shrink) of `1`
- [`flex-basis`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#propdef-flex-basis) of `auto`

Which means:

- They won't grow within the flex container;
- They will shrink evenly
- They will be sized based on their contents.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/k2vojkoc/)**

[image: Default behavior of flex items]

Thus, if you give `width`<sup>**1**</sup> - with a value higher than the available space inside the flex container - to a flex item, they'll shrink evenly.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/k2vojkoc/1/)**

[image: Giving a large width to a flex item]

If you give `flex-shrink` of `2` to the bigger one, e.g. `#child2`, it will shrink two times more than the other one, e.g `#child1`.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/k2vojkoc/2/)**

[image: Applying flex shrink to a flex item]

---

### The effect of `flex` property

[`flex`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#propdef-flex) is a shorthand of `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, `flex-basis` properties; It accepts 3 values which the second and third values as optional.

**Syntax**

```
none | [ <‘flex-grow’> <‘flex-shrink’>? || <‘flex-basis’> ]
```

The default value of `flex` is `0 1 auto`. However if you use the **one-value syntax** - i.e. `flex: 1;` - the computed value would be `flex: 1 1 0%`.

In order to understand the difference between `flex-basis` of `auto` and `0` take a look at the picture below which is taken from [Flexible Box Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-basis):

[image: Flex basis property example]

> **Figure 6.** A diagram showing the difference between "absolute" flex (starting from a basis of zero) and "relative" flex (starting from a
>   basis of the item’s content size). The three items have flex factors
>   of 1, 1, and 2, respectively.

By giving `flex: 1`<sup>**2**</sup> to the `#child2`, due to `flex-basis: 0` it won't respect the width of the flex item's contents anymore. Hence the computed width of the `#child2` would be equal to the available space within the flex container.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/k2vojkoc/3/)**

[image: Added flex: 1 to a flex item]

In addition, by giving `flex: 1`<sup>**2**</sup> to the `#child` item (as well as the `#child2`), the flex items are forced to grow evenly, no matter if they have an explicit `width` or not; No matter how much their `width` value is<sup>**3**</sup>.

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/k2vojkoc/4/)**

[image: Added flex: 1 to all flex items]

---

### Last but not least!

In order to have a multi-line flex container, In addition to having `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container, if you have given `flex-grow: 1` (i.e. `flex: 1;`) to a flex item, you have to give that `flex-basis: 100%` as well (in short: `flex: 1 100%`).

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/k2vojkoc/5/)**

[image: multi-line flex container]

---

<sup>1. Equal to `flex-basis` without specifying `flex-grow`.</sup>
<sup>2. Equal to `flex-grow: 1;`, `flex-shrink: 1;` and `flex-basis: 0` while `flex-shrink: 1;` is applied by default.</sup>
<sup>3. While `flex-basis` would affect the computed width.</sup>